# How to get rid of nullReference Exception in LinQ Query?

Tags: linq

gridview_new is a form class

```
private checkNulls[] CheckNulls()
    {
        checkNulls Cntrl;
        checkNulls[] cntrlsToupdate = new checkNulls[15];
        using (gridview_new IterateThroughCntrls = new gridview_new())
        {              

            for (int i = 5; i < 18; i++)
            {
                var getCntrl = 
                    IterateThroughCntrls.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(x => x.TabIndex ==  i).SingleOrDefault();

                if (!(getCntrl.Text == ""))
                {
                    Cntrl = (checkNulls)(i);
                    cntrlsToupdate[i - 5] = Cntrl;
                }
            }
        }

        return cntrlsToupdate;
    }
```

Get Control is getting a null value even though there is a control at tab-index 5.

Comment: First thing to fix is your naming - your type and variable names make this code really hard to read at the moment. You also need to tell us what the conversion between `int` and `checkNulls` is - presumably this is a custom conversion, but you haven't told us anything about it.

Comment: Are there also controls with TabIndex == 6, 7, ..., 17?

Answer (score 2):

First, `...OrDefault` returns the default value for a given type, in case of reference types (like `Control`) you get `null`. So then you could simply check that:

```
if(getCntrl != null)
{
    // safe....
}
```

If you want the text of the control and `""` as default if the `Where` has found no matching controls, use `Select` + `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
string getCntrlText = IterateThroughCntrls.Controls.Cast<Control>()
    .Where(x => x.TabIndex ==  i)
    .Select(ctrl => ctrl.Text)
    .DefaultIfEmpty("")
    .Single();
```

Note that i've used `Single` since i've provided a default value.

Note that `Single...` throws an exception (as opposed to `First...`) if multiple items match the predicate. Normally it's used with key properties where it should be impossible to find multiple elments. So `First`(or `FirstOrDefault`) seems to be more appropriate here.